# Retrieve css tag values in python

Tags: python, css

I am looking to retrieve the value "312 votes" from the below tag hierarchy:

```
<div class="rating-rank right">
<span class="rating-votes-div-65211">312 votes</span>
</div>
```

The problem seems to be that the span tag has a unique identifier for every values in the page. In the above case '65211'. What should i do to retrieve the required value?

I am using soup.select to get the values. But it doesn't seem to work.

```
for tag in soup.select('div.rating-rank right'):
    try:
        print(tag.string)
    except KeyError:
        pass
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You try to select a `right` element that follows a `div` with class `rating-rank`. You can select what you want like this:

```
soup.select("div.rating-rank.right span")
```

With css selectors you have to read them from right to left. So `div.rating-rank.right span` means I want a `span` element which is after a `div` element having `rating-rank`, `right` as classes. From the moment you identified your span elements, you can print their contents like you already do.

Comment: yes it worked wonderfully. :) Could you pls briefly explain how this worked?

Comment: Maybe it's better to tell me what you don't understand

Comment: like what does the dot and the space signify?

Comment: For your particular case I explain it in the answer. But it's a very broad subject to explain in general. You can check this [resource](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#css-selectors) to find more.